# If an animal is not a predator (e.g. a herbivore), but has nothing that eats it, what is it called?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, animals, biology

Most animals I have heard of, such as killer whales, great white sharks, and other apex predators are, well, predators. But what would you call an apex non-predator?

Comment: Isn't "apex predator" a kind of predator? It's like you're asked if there are any squares that are not rectangles - no, there aren't.

Comment: The phrase [with no natural enemies](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+no+natural+enemies%22) comes to mind. But it's often applied to “invasive species” that aren't necessarily particularly ***big***, and I assume that OP wouldn't class cane toads, coffee berry borers, etc. as *“**apex** [species]”* because they're  too small.

Comment: A herbivore which is not eaten by any predator is not a part of the 'food chain'. It just snacks on vegetation and minds its own business. I would call it an 'alpha herbivore' for want of a better term.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @Nigel J: the term "alpha herbivore" is in use, and probably means what OP intended, please see https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22alpha+herbivore%22&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=%22alpha+herbivore%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0.3297.8697.0.9193.2.2.0.0.0.0.280.503.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.2.501.N6r-rmf3rSY If you are convinced please consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: I'd call it _too big to be eaten_.

Comment: An 'apex predator that is not a predator' is an error in need of editing.

Comment: What's an animal that is eaten called? The prey of another animal, right?  Those are prey animals. So, the opposite might be: unpreyed-on herbivores. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

[Apex predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator) sits on top of the food chain and can eat any animal below it including other predators. Adult lions hunting as a pride are Africa's apex predators on land. Killer whales are apex predators of the seas and there are [cases](http://www.newsweek.com/orcas-killing-great-white-sharks-eating-livers-607002) of killer whales attacking and killing the other great predator of the sea, the great white shark.

Herbivores are not called apex predators even if they are prey to no natural predators themself. I suppose you  mean absolutely top herbivore animals like healthy adult male African Elephants whom even lions will not attack? Adult male lions are typically called "King of the Jungle" for being the apex land predator but there are many [articles](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=elephant+king+of+the+jungle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=dISVWuC_NIyjX6_gmdgC) that suggest the healthy adult male elephant ***should be*** called "[King of the Jungle](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1337157/Real-king-jungle-Bull-elephant-chases-lion-dares-disturb-him.html)." Its only [predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_trade) [not natural but by hunting] are human beings.

Similarly the healthy adult male hippopotamus, a herbivore which has no predator in the river, is called "[King of the river](http://wanderlord.com/hippopotamus-king-river/)."

Comment: Terms like predator/prey/herbivore/carnivore/etc. refer to the species as a whole, not any particular individual. So, while there might be a individual adult male African Elephant that lions prefer not to attack, as a species elephants are indeed preyed upon by predators including lions, crocodiles, and us.

Comment: Also: "which is *unprepared* in the river"? Perhaps you mean something like 'unrivaled' or 'unparalleled'?

Comment: Your point is well made @Mark Beadles but it is not an individual male elephant. Yes, the term "King of the jungle" can apply only to the specific subset of "healthy adult male elephants" which are uniformly not attacked by any animals including lions. Thanks for pointing out "unprepared" which is an autocorrect error.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Only baby/juvenile/sick elephants are really subject to non-human predation; but by that standard, there really aren't any apex *predators*, either.

Comment: Very true @1006a: *a pride of adult lions* is the real apex predator.

Comment: @1006a I was attempting to convey that just because some elephants aren't attacked by lions doesn't mean that lions aren't predators of elephants. An elephant isn't an apex species.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @English Student, the term '**alpha herbivore**' (which I thought I had made up myself) is actually documented :

> The object was to re-introduce the alpha herbivore in the North American West.

[Ecology and Wonder in the Canadian Rocky Mountains by Robert W Sandford](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2aPnUlT5HAkC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=%22alpha+herbivore%22&source=bl&ots=FC1OCM4-pd&sig=crUTRL5JT2UsIb5-gOmEIIVUQTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8yKuMx8bZAhXKe8AKHUN4DbIQ6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=%22alpha%20herbivore%22&f=false)

Comment: This obviously just means 'principal / main' herbivore, not one that has no predators. The term is already taken.